# f# assembly reference issue with mongodb.driver under monodevelop ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mongodb, f#, ubuntu-14.04, monodevelop

as a noob to f# i try to get my feet wet on ubuntu.
With monodevelop (version 5.9.5) i want to install the MongoDB.Driver package from the "add packages" package manager. It yields:

Could not install package 'MongoDB.Bson 2.0.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Any clues how to fix this?

There are similar issues with previous version of monodevelop but all solutions if found didn't work for me.

thanks
frank s.

Comment: It sounds like you need to change your project to target .NET 4.5 instead of 4.0.

Comment: noober error: how do i do this?

Answer (score 2):

As in comments try changing to target .NET 4.5.
Right-click on project in Solution Explorer -> Options -> Build -> General -> Target Framework.

[image: Options]

Comment: no such thing "target framework". Only option under options->build->general is "output directory".. What to do? Wrong setup?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank you. Now i see it. I opened the wrong menu. Not the solution but the *project* options is right to choose the .net target version. 
Now it works!
Thank you very much indeed!
Frank